# Resilience4j max waiting time for a service call

Tags: resilience4j

I'm looking through the docs of Resilience4j and I cannot seem to find the configuration for a time limiter.

I work in Spring Boot 2 and I use configure the setting in an application.yml. So far it looks like this:

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  instances:
    frap:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      ringBufferSizeInClosedState: 3
      ringBufferSizeInHalfOpenState: 3
      waitDurationInOpenState: 10s
      failureRateThreshold: 20
      waitDuration: 10s
```

What property should I add to make it fail fast?

Answer (score 2):

A `@TimeLimiter` annotation is not supported in Spring Boot yet. 
But a time limit is simple to implement. Your method must return a `CompletableFuture` and just invoke `future.get()`. That's it.

Feel free to contribute a Spring AOP Aspect ;)

https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/430

But keep in mind that it is better to configure a timelimit on the protocol level. For example in your HTTP client.